# Live Agent: bug with <liveAgent:clientChatQueuePosition />?

Tags: liveagent

Has anyone got `<liveAgent:clientChatQueuePosition />` to work correctly with Live Agent in a custom chat page?  I was trying to do this, and I could not get it to show the queue position.  After looking at the source code and playing with the Firefox element inspector, I discovered that the queue position is inside a `<div>`, and that for some reason the style of that div is set to "display:none".  So I added this javascript at the end of my custom chat page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      document.getElementById('liveAgentQueuePosition').style.display = 'inline' ;
  </script>
```

and then it started working!  This happened on both Chrome and Firefox, so it does not look like a browser specific issue.  So again I ask, has anyone got this to work without the workround I had to do?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Choice for routing? When routing is set to choice, the agent gets to pick up whichever chat requests that are pending, regardless of the queue position. Thus, the queue position is meaningless, so the queue position is hidden by CSS.

Comment: Tom, I am not using Choice, I am using Most Available